# ArcScene Extrusion is Too High

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I am bringing a parcels shapefile and buildings shapefile into ArcScene.

They come in okay and look fine as 2D features.

When I extrude the building outlines based on height they look as if they are 20+ miles tall and they do not seems to be proportional.

Is there a way to set units when I extrude?

Answer (score 1):

The heights may be measured using different units to the layer's coordinate system. You can apply a factor to the extrusion once you figure out the correct conversion. See *extrusion value or expression* on the Extrusion tab:

[image]